# Label Coordinates in ggplot 2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, coordinates

I have drawn a cumulative distribution graph in R. I want to label the points on the graph when the Y-axis (Cumulative probability) has 0.1, 0.2, 0.3...etc (some specific Y values) with both X and Y coordinates. For example, I want to mark the point  (1250,0.5) in the graph and labelthat value in the graph. I would appreciate it if you could help me.

[image]

Comment: Take a look again at [ask], since this is entirely too vague right now. We have no idea what you're looking at—what type of data, what type of plot, how you're trying to visualize the coordinates, what trouble you're having with finding them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add points using a separate `geom_point` function.

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_minimal())

# Loading data
iris = as_tibble(iris)
```

Now I filter points that I want to highlight.

```
# filter out points to highlight (say which have sepal.length 5, 4.4 or 4.9)
iris_highlight = iris %>% 
   filter(Sepal.Length %in% c(5.0, 4.4, 4.9))
```

Now comes the meat.

```
# Plot
iris %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
   geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
   geom_point(data = iris_highlight, 
              aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, colour = "red"))
```

[image: example plot]